# Fraud litmus test for political fund raising?

Tags: united-states, fraud

[Media has reported](https://abcnews.go.com/US/trump-rnc-raised-hundreds-millions-pushing-baseless-election/story?id=75633798&cid=clicksource_4380645_5_heads_hero_live_hero_related) that the Republican National Committee (RNC) and Donald Trump have raised hundreds of millions on the basis of election fraud, which as I understand it has no basis in fact.

What contours or bright-lines must be crossed (litmus test) to identify [fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraud) or running afoul of the law for fundraising based upon a false / unproven premise as cited in the media example?

IANAL and would like to keep the replies focused on law and avoid politics.  A dual-prong explanation is appreciated: a layman's explanation to be followed by legal jargon

Comment: Generally speaking, political parties engage in massive assertion of unproven premises. You can then surmise that political speech is fairly well protected in the US.

Comment: Agreed.  Free political speech is fairly well protected.  That being said, the introduction of  money / fundraising, I suspect that there are rules that govern / limit behaviors

Comment: Relevant https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-11-26/pro-trump-group-donor-sues-over-failure-to-expose-election-fraud But hardly the first such case https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2017/08/lawsuit-republicans-repeal-replace-obamacare I'd be curious to know such cases that were actually won in court as opposed to settled etc.